# How to get string or int64 from object time in golang?

Tags: go, time, timestamp

I get from input source timestamp and then I make time '00:00:00' for this timestamp. Now I need to get timestamp from object time

```
timestamp_int:= 1532009163
time := time.Date(
            time.Unix(int64(timestamp_int), 0).UTC().Year(),
            time.Unix(int64(timestamp_int), 0).UTC().Month(),
            time.Unix(int64(timestamp_int), 0).UTC().Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0,
            time.Unix(int64(timestamp_int), 0).UTC().Location())
new_time := time.Format("timestamp") //here i need to get new timestamp
```

Comment: In this question you've stated you want: a string, an int64, a time (of the format "00:00:00"), and a timestamp. Which is it that you need?

Comment: Shure. I edit it

Comment: If you need to get the Unix timestamp from a `time.Time`, use `Time.Unix()`: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix

Comment: @jimB So it works. Thanks. I`m idiot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the timestamp in seconds by using the [`Unix`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix) method.

```
timestamp := 1532009163
t := time.Unix(int64(timestamp), 0)
newTimestamp := time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix()
fmt.Println(newTimestamp)
// 1531958400
```